# Storing Calculations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I have an application where there are 1000 columns in database, each column value is calculated based upon a formula. This formula can be modified by a user. I need a way to map these calculations to a particular column in database in such a way that it can be edited by a user.

For example: my table has 3 columns `COL_A, COL_B & COL_C`

I have a calculation which says: `VALUE = COL_A + COL_B`

In future, if a user wants to change this calculation say for example: `VALUE = COL_A + COL_B  + COL_C` then this change should get reflected.

Which is the best way to do this ?

Thanks,

Ujjwal Soni

Comment: I'd be minded to do this in the application rather than SQL Server. To do it in SQL Server itself would require dynamic SQL or updating object definitions dynamically to reflect the new formula.

Comment: to do this you are going to either need some sort of expression parser, or you need to limit people's choices by giving them a list of fields and a list of operators that you can easily write procedural code to branch on and do the requested calculation

Answer (score 3):

You can write an SQL scalar function that accepts parameters and returns a value. 
The function can then be called by passing the necessary parameters. The function can later be modified to suit your needs. Below is an example to create a function and how to call it.

```
-- Create the function
CREATE FUNCTION [Rmas].[functionName](@valA int, @valB int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @answer int;
  SELECT @answer = @valA + @valB;
RETURN @answer
END

-- Call the function to access the calculation
SELECT [Rmas].[functionName](2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your base table alone, write the calculations as functions and then create a view which will select from your table and use functions for calculated fields. Later, you can change the calculation in the function without changing the table or the view.